# Getting This Error : TemplateDoesNotExist at post/1/

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Can anyone please help me with this error when i am trying to access the page it shows this error

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist

Exception Value: firstblog/post_detail.html

Exception Location: C:\Users\ADMIN\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 47, in select_template

**views.py**

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('about/',views.about, name='blog-about'),
]
```

Comment: Is the issue resolved? Please mark any of the correct answers as accepted to close it.

Comment: I checked and seems like the once you accepted doesn't solve your issue. Please don't accept incorrect answers. If you have a solution of your own, you can post and accept that, otherwise accept the one I have posted. @bhavikjain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `template_name` attribute in your generic class-based view:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'firstblog/post_detail.html'
```

Comment: @BhavikJain Please accept the answer if your issue is resolved.

Comment: the template_name is default .... the problem of the error message is that the post_detail.html file is missing.

Answer (score 0):

In Class Based View if you do not define template_name Django looks for the standard pattern <app_label>/<model_name>_detail.html which is in your case "firstblog/post_detail.html" ... that is where the error message is coming from. You need to create /firstblock/templates/firstblock/post_detail.html